# How to make CSS URL background images show up in localhost?

Tags: css, localhost, xampp, background-image

I just installed xampp and I brought one of my live sites into it to be able to start working from localhost.

So to view my site, I navigate to localhost/example.com

I noticed some issues with images when on my html, I had for example:

```
<img src="/new_pictures/05.jpg" alt="Central Market"/>
```

Image wouldn't show up, but then I removed the `/` and this works:

```
<img src="new_pictures/05.jpg" alt="Central Market"/>
```

I seem to have a similar problem with the CSS background image, but I can't get it to work-if I remove the / there, the image doesn't show up on the live site.  How do I make the background image show up on localhost?

Example CSS (works in live site but not localhost):

```
.outeremailcontainer {
height:60px;
width: 275px;
background-image:url(/images/feather_email2.jpg);
text-align:center;
float:right;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try background-image:url(/example.com/images/feather_email2.jpg);

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The image paths in your stylesheet should be where the image is **relative to the stylesheet**, for example if your `.css` file is in a directory like this on your site:

```
/css/styles.css
```

Your path should look like this (go up a directory, then into `images`)

```
background-image:url(../images/feather_email2.jpg);
```

Comment: Indeed that did it.  Thanks!  It's strange to me that the path was working fine on the live site...

Comment: @Joel - I'm guessing that your site on localhost is something like `localhost/mySite/` as the root, and not just `localhost/`?  That would be the reason :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`base`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag - supported in most popular browsers - and then supply paths relative to the `href` attribute of the `base` tag. Or make sure you supply correct paths relative to the CSS stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Try using `./` instead of `/` and make sure that you are specifying the correct path.